# React Typescript useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I'm trying to create a custom hook that accepts a non-mandatory date as a prop, I need to call this hook with a different date or without it, and if there is a date, I should return exactly the type of this date, for example f(string) => string[].
I'm sorry, I can't show you the real code, but I created an equivalent code.

```
import { useStatem, useEffect } from "react";

type IProps<T> = {
  isValid: boolean;
  testData?: T[];
};
interface IState<T> {
  error: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  data: T[];
}
type InitialTypes = "john" | 55;

export function useSome<T extends InitialTypes>({
  testData,
  isValid,
}: IProps<T>) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<IState<T>>({
    error: false,
    loading: false,
    data: [],
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    // some logic
    setValue((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, data: ["john"] }));
  }, []);

  return [value.data];
}
```

when I try to setValue I get error :

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(prevState: IState<T>) => { data: "john"[]; error: boolean; loading: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IState<T>>'.   
Type '(prevState: IState<T>) => { data: "john"[]; error: boolean; loading: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '(prevState: IState<T>) => IState<T>'.     
Call signature return types '{ data: "john"[]; error: boolean; loading: boolean; }' and 'IState<T>' are incompatible.       
The types of 'data' are incompatible between these types.         
Type '"john"[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.           
Type '"john"' is not assignable to type 'T'.             
'"john"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'InitialTypes'.
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, the issue is caused by `const [value, setValue] = useState<IState<T>>({error: false, loading: false, data: []});` line.

In your `IState` type you have a generic `T` which is used to determine the type of array hold by `data` variable as follow:

```
interface IState<T> {
    error: boolean,
    loading: boolean,
    data: T[],
}
```

Whereas, in `const [value, setValue] = useState<IState<T>>({error: false, loading: false, data: []});`, you have forgot to specify/provide the generic type T.

So, instead of `useState<IState<T>>` it should be either `useState<IState<string>>` or `useState<IState<InitialTypes>>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, in this case i return the date as type alies "john" | 55 , I need to return only "john" type or 55.